# Passing parameters in a loose-coupled, scalable way

Tags: c++, oop, templates, stl

I recently took on a project requiring me to build a UI in wxWidgets, but I had to follow the lead after the architect. His methods were, "interesting". I don't want to disparage the guy but he used an odd mix of patterns in his design, a lot of old school stuff even though the project was built to C++17 compliance. For example, he didn't like using smart pointers opting instead to instantiate everything on the stack, and other bizarre stuff. Anyway, the ui's header file had a huge pile of pointers to all its widgets. I find this style of design painful, after a few dozen pointer instances I found the code rather difficult to follow. I tried to show the man a bit more manageable design using an abstract wxWidget factory pattern with descendant factories for each widget we needed to instantiate, and more composition for various things, and he found it "interesting" but proceeded to keep doing things his way. No matter.

I've decided to take on a redesign on my own using that abstract factory pattern. This works rather well and I've maintained a very loose coupling between the widget declarations in the header and the implementations in the impl file. The stuff the various factories create don't even need to be wxwidgets, could be anything, this makes me happy. What doesn't make me happy is how I'm handling the parameters necessary for each widget.

Loose example with lots of omission;

```
widge1 factory: wxWidget1instance = new wxWidget1(foo, bar, baz);
widget2instance = new wxwidget2(param1, param2);
```

and so on. Of course the various params are of different types.

The various factory sub classes spit out the widgets and they are then loaded into main class vector members ready for use.

I'm passing the params using a stuct with a bunch of types necessary for each different widget and simply leaving the unneeded params null. This works, but naturally leaves a bad taste in my mouth. For one thing I'm sure this breaks my carefully crafted loose coupling between instances and implementation, and whatever else I'm not seeing yet but I know I'll encounter other issues.

Curious to hear from others how they would do this? Pointers to functions? Some kind of polymorphic object? Some kind of cool STL feature I'm not seeing? Is this a really bad design?  If so I can take it. Constructive criticism please, share your thoughts, and much appreciated.

Comment: You should talk to your architect about _why_ things are instantiated on the stack.  There are valid design reasons to do so, but without any kind of real context demonstrating the pattern (beyond your personal impressions), the best person to ask is the architect.  Remember, these people are often (though not always) thinking about things beyond your sphere of vision and knowledge.

Comment: I don't see an actual question that can be answered here.

Comment: @interval it will help if you will provide full interface of your factory and couple of widgets

Comment: Not too sure what is missing. Its a simple question. I want to use a fully OOP way of passing parameters to a collection of similar apis. Why in the world would you require specific code for such a general question? As for paddy's response; i am quite sure that its a bad design based on the architect's predilections and other old ways of thinking. In any case, this has nothing to do with my question. Let's remove the case that everything is instantiated on the stack. The real question is how do I provide params of different types to a collection of related apis. Its really that simple.

Comment: No real suggestions so I'm going to try to write some sort of object that will maybe count the number of params for any api, use reflection for determining the type, something like that.